# angular dynmaic document height from top to bottom

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, angular-material, angular-dom-sanitizer

How to calculate each and every page height from top to bottom in angular ?
This syntax work in JavaScript but give error in angular

```
console.log( (document.height !== undefined) ? document.height : document.body.offsetHeight+'px');
```

What I want is to have each page height but when items are added  dynamically , it should give me the new height of page.

Comment: Can you show the error gave in angular ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
console.log(window.innerHeight);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Renderer2, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: '<p *ngFor='let item of arr'>item {{item?.name}}</p>',
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
arr=[];
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.calculatePageHeight();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.addElementToDOM();//like your API call
      this.calculatePageHeight();
    }, 4000); // Adjust the delay based on your use case
  }

  addElementToDOM() {
    this.arr=[
.......
];
  }

  calculatePageHeight() {
    const documentHeight = Math.max(
      document.documentElement.clientHeight,
      window.innerHeight || 0
    );

    console.log('Updated Document Height: ' + documentHeight + 'px');
  }
}
```